# Differential Equations: Finding period about an equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sketch the solutions $y(t)$ of the initial value problem and draw the phase plane for:

$y''=6y-6y^{2}$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=-2$

Sketch $y$ vs $t$. Find the period near the equilibrium $y=1$.

I am able to graph $y'$ vs $y$ and draw the phase portrait from there. As well as calculate the constant $k$ for the initial conditions given but I am unsure of what to do from there.

$0.5(y')^2-3y^2+2y^3=k$

So, $k=-1$ but I am unsure how to draw $y$ vs $t$ or calculate the period about the equilibrium $y=1$ which is stable.

I can upload a picture of my phase portrait and graph of the function if that clarifies the question.

Comment: If you substitute in the given initial conditions you should get $k=1$ (don't forget to also use $y'(0)=-2$).

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the period near an equilibrium you can linearise the differential equation by calculating the [Jacobian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), $J$, such that the differential equation can be approximated with

$$
y''=J_{y=1}(y-1).
$$